# Javascript Shuffle Array from Text File

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, text-files

I am looking to pull 5 "random" lines from a text file while not repeating any. Each line from the text file has html code which would be inserted into a side menu. I have read up on the Fisher–Yates shuffle but not sure how to incorporate it in this manner with javascript. Presently I am using the following coding for pulling a single 1 line from the file:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
    // get the file contents
    var fileContent = this.responseText;
    // split into lines
    var fileContentLines = fileContent.split( '\n' );
    // get a random index (line number)
    var randomLineIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * fileContentLines.length );
    // extract the value
    var randomLine = fileContentLines[ randomLineIndex ];

    // add the random line in a div
    document.getElementById( 'random-testimonial' ).innerHTML = randomLine;
};
request.open( 'GET', 'content.txt', true );
request.send();
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Where is your shuffle code? Currently you're only getting the file and splitting it into an Array of lines. Where's your best try?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Tehk5

Answer (score 0):

You just need to repeat the code in `request.onload()` five times, don't you? (Except appending to the div html rather than setting it.) Just use a loop. You don't need to implement a shuffle: the random (0..N-1) integer expression you're using is all you need to select random lines.

Although you probably want to prevent duplicates. Maybe check for a substring match before the append.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
    var i = 0;
    // get the file contents
    var fileContent = this.responseText;
    // split into lines
    var fileContentLines = fileContent.split( '\n' );

    var target = document.getElementById( 'random-testimonial' );
    var targetHTML = target.innerHTML;

    while ( i < 5 ) {
        // get a random index (line number)
        var randomLineIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * fileContentLines.length );
        // extract the value
        var randomLine = fileContentLines[ randomLineIndex ];

        // add the random line in a div if not duplicate            
        if ( ! targetHTML.contains(randomLine) ) {
            targetHTML += randomLine;
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    target.innerHTML = targetHTML;
};
request.open( 'GET', 'content.txt', true );
request.send();
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I need to prevent duplicate line pulls. I gave this a go but immediately receive a javascript uncaught error: 

`code` links.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: targetHTML.contains is not a functionrequest.onload @ content.js:17
`code`

Comment: @UltraWebHosting: well, that's odd. The `.innerHTML()` method should return a string, and strings have a `.contains()` method. Check what `targetHTML` gives you at the console. Are you sure the `id` 'random-testimonial' exists? If not, `targetHTML` will be `null` and cause the error.

Comment: I can't see any reason for that error, but one thing is, in the code above, the `targetHTML` value doesn't actually get saved back into the `.innerHTML` (so the lines won't show up). I'll fix it.

Comment: @UltraWebHosting: okay, I've fixed that error and tested the code with the HTML you posted (`<div id="random-content"><script src="content.js"></script></div>`) and it works for me (after changing the `id` from `random-testimonial` to `random-content`).

Comment: On that website, when I checked just now, the `request.onload` function is still the one you originally posted in your question.

Comment: @pyrocrsty Yes, that is what I thought you updated on codeshare but didn't realize you updated your original reply. I have updated the content.js to reflect the update but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> you could try this. generate 5 random numbers between 1 and n (where
>   `n = fileContentLines.length)` say n1, n2,n3,n4 and n5. Then you get
>   your 5 lines as `fileContentLines[n1]` and so on... use this code
>   snippet to generate 5 random numbers:

```
`var arr = []
while(arr.length < 5){
  var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*n)
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
  }
  if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
}`
```